# How can I use opencv to capture IP video in an android application?

Tags: android, opencv

I have already launched a mjpeg-streaming server which I can use browser to see the stream video in this address: http://192.168.4.2:9002/?action=stream ( I am using local network )

I would like to use opencv to access this stream video in an android application.

I imported openCV 2.4.10 library and did something like:

```
VideoCapture video = new VideoCapture();
video.open("http://192.168.4.2:9002/?action=stream");
```

However it didn't work as I can't pass a string in the open function.

Please give me some suggestions on it. Many Thanks.

Comment: there's no way to read a stream via VideoCapture on android. you can use imdecode(), but you'll have to do the networking on your own.

Comment: @berak you means I need to use imdecode() to decode the IP video first, and then pass to openCV? Do you have any example on it? Thanks.